# Optimising & Scaling Celery with RabbitMQ for I/O bound tasks

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, rabbitmq, celery

I have a celery task that accepts a keyword from the producer and uses the keyword to query database - `DB1` and then inserts it into another database - `DB2`. One task cycle takes about 15 seconds.

**Deployment**

1. RabbitMQ Broker takes care of routing the tasks
2. GCP Managed Instance Group are the consumers(deployed as containers). Each node size is 30 Core CPU 64GB Mem
3. DB1 - SQL Server (managed externally where I have read-only access, I perform raw SQL queries)
4. DB2 - PostgresSQL (I manage this with SQLAlchemy as the ORM)

**What I'm trying to achieve**

The distributed consumers should be able to handle 10000s of task in a second from the queue.

**IssuesI faced**

1. Two consumers were picking up the same tasks. I was able to fix it with the following config

```
app.conf.task_acks_late = False
```

2. Postgresql Connection issues during writes

```
# postgres sqlalchemy config

# create database engine
engine = create_engine(DB_URL, poolclass=QueuePool,
                       pool_size=30000,
                       max_overflow=6000,
                       pool_timeout=120)

# creating db session
SessionInstance = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = SessionInstance()

Session = scoped_session(SessionInstance)
```

```
# write in tasks.py
from psql_config import Session

...
session = Session()
with session.begin_nested():
    db_manager = WriteRawDBManager(session)
    db_manager.update_record(
        record=record_result,
    )
    Session.close()
...
```

There is no issue with the writes.

3. Celery Concurrency

```
celery -A tasks worker --pool threads --concurrency=15000
```

Just increasing the concurrency does not seem to effective enough. As I understand this is a not a CPU intensive task and hence even with so many workers the CPU usage is less than 10%. It would be a waste of resources to add more nodes, as they are with very minimal CPU usage.

This is a weekly task that the producer would add 6 million messages to the queue within a span of 60 mins. I want to be able to consume and process all 6 million in a matter of 120 mins or less. Also, keeping in mind about the writes to postgresql db (as i have faced connection blocking issues)

It would be great if someone to direct me to better resources for this.